# Adobe Acrobat Javascript setPageRotations does not rotate page

Tags: javascript, adobe, acrobat

I am trying to rotate active pdf by a button click in `execDialog` by `setPageRotations` method of `Adobe Acrobat Javascript API` using action wizard. Below is the `javascript` code I use.

```
var dialogBox =
{
    description:
    {
        elements:
        [{  
            type: "static_text",
            name: "Rotate",
            alignment: "align_center",
        },
        {
            type: "button",  // add a custom button
            item_id: "rtlf",
            name: "Left",
            alignment: "align_center",
        },
        {
            type: "button",  // add a custom button
            item_id: "rtrt",
            name: "Right",
            alignment: "align_center",
        },
        {
            type: "ok",
            name: "Close",
            item_id: "cdoc"
        }]
    },
    commit: function(dialog)
    {
        app.alert("This script from action is working");
    },
    rtlf: function () // handler of the custom component by id name
    { 
        this.setPageRotations(0,0,90);
    },
    rtrt: function () // handler of the custom component by id name
    { 
        this.setPageRotations(0,0,270);
    }
};
app.execDialog(dialogBox);
```

It shows the alert "This script from action is working". But it doesn't seem to apply rotations as I mentioned in `setPageRotations`.

How should we do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the dialog object definition, "this" refers to the dialogBox object itself. You need to pass a reference to the PDF document object in order to perform operations on it while the dialog is open. The code I added to the end of your dialog description defines a new function that defines a pdfDoc property in the dialog object then calls executes the dialog. I can then call the function and pass in the dialog object ***and*** the PDF document object. ***Outside*** of an object definition, "this" refers to the PDF Document itself. Also, notice the change in the button callbacks. Now they refer to "this" (this dialog) but then to the pdfDoc property which was set to the PDF Document itself by doTheDialog().

```
var dialogBox =
{
    description:
    {
        elements:
        [{  
            type: "static_text",
            name: "Rotate",
            alignment: "align_center",
        },
        {
            type: "button",  // add a custom button
            item_id: "rtlf",
            name: "Left",
            alignment: "align_center",
        },
        {
            type: "button",  // add a custom button
            item_id: "rtrt",
            name: "Right",
            alignment: "align_center",
        },
        {
            type: "ok",
            name: "Close",
            item_id: "cdoc"
        }]
    },
    commit: function(dialog)
    {
        app.alert("This script from action is working");
    },
    rtlf: function () // handler of the custom component by id name
    { 
        this.pdfDoc.setPageRotations(0,0,90);
    },
    rtrt: function () // handler of the custom component by id name
    { 
        this.pdfDoc.setPageRotations(0,0,270);
    }
};

function doTheDialog(dialog, pdfDoc) {    
    dialog.pdfDoc = pdfDoc;
    var retVal = app.execDialog(dialog);
}

doTheDialog(dialogBox, this);
```